# TypeError: can't convert type 'ndarray' to numerator/denominator

Tags: python, numpy

[Error which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgTKV.png)  Here is my code. I am not able to understand this error. I have tried a lot but not getting the correct solution. Please help me to know what is the error.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
import statistics 
from os import read
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/content/4.forged4.avi')

countF = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) # calculate no of frames per sec

while True:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if ret:
     gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     gray = np.array(gray_img).astype(int)
     frames.append(gray)
     #cv2_imshow(gray_img) 
     radius = 3

     p = 8 * radius
     lbp =  local_binary_pattern(gray_img,p, radius, method = 'uniform') 
     print(lbp)
     val =  statistics.stdev(lbp) # caluculated standard deviation
     print(val)
     if val == 0:
       print("Authenticated")
     else:
       print("Forgery Detected!")
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the code:  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

`statistics.stdev` expects as argument an iterable (e.g. a list) of real numbers with at least two values. You are passing to it the variable `lbp` which does not satisfy that requirement (it's a list of lists). You can run simple experiments to see how functions behave if the documentation is not quite clear. Here's e.g. what I did:

```
$ python3
>>> import statistics
>>> help(statistics.stdev)
Help on function stdev in module statistics:

stdev(data, xbar=None)
    Return the square root of the sample variance.

    See ``variance`` for arguments and other details.
    ...
>>> help(statistics.variance)
Help on function variance in module statistics:

variance(data, xbar=None)
    Return the sample variance of data.

    data should be an iterable of Real-valued numbers, with at least two
    values.
    ....
>>> l = [[1.0 ,2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]
>>> statistics.stdev(l)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: can't convert type 'list' to numerator/denominator
>>> l = [1.0 ,2.0, 3.0]
>>> statistics.stdev(l)
1.0
>>>
```

As you can see, passing a list of lists of numbers to `stdev` produces the error you get, whereas passing a list of numbers works properly.

The moral of the story is that the local binary pattern `lbp` that you calculate two lines above is not of the proper type to pass to `stdev`.

Now, that's the reason that the python program fails, but it's likely that the underlying reason for this is confusion on your part about what should be done. *If* it makes sense to calculate the standard deviation of the entries in `lbp` (and it's a big if that I cannot answer for you), then you could try flattening `lbp`, which is a list of lists down to a single list, before passing it to `stdev`. But does it make sense to do that? Only you can answer that question and only if you understand the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want forged frames from the video. How can I get using this?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do or how you can do it: as I said, only you can answer that question. All I'm doing is trying to answer your question about the error you get and where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

@rohit-sharma, you must flatten your data before use in `statistics` module.

Assume `lbp` variable is a ndarray:

change:

```
     val =  statistics.stdev(lbp) # caluculated standard deviation
```

to:

```
     val =  statistics.stdev(lbp.flatten()) # caluculated standard deviation
```

Hope this helps.